# Iron Router conflict with Angular-UI router

Tags: meteor, angular-ui-router

I'm using an Angular-Meteor solution with my web app and I opted to use angular-ui:router over iron-router. I ran into issues when I decided to use Houston Admin which uses iron-router under the hood. Is there a way to restrict iron-router to /admin/* routes?

When I navigate my app normally, I get a message from iron-router in the view saying the route doesn't exist but it does under angular-ui:rouer.

EDIT: Defining the routes within iron router is getting me somewhere but now my angular-ui view is being displayed twice.

```
//Iron-Router
Router.route('/(.*)', function (){});

//UI-Router
angular.module("test").config(
function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, $locationProvider){

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

$stateProvider
  .state('main', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'client/app/main/views/main.ng.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
  })
  .state('profile',{
    url: '/profile/:user_id',
    templateUrl: 'client/app/main/views/profile.ng.html',
    controller: 'ProfileCtrl',
    resolve: {
      currentUser: function($meteor){
        return $meteor.requireUser();
      }
    }
  });

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
```

});

EDIT2: When the page refreshes it doesn't double display the view. That happens after I change route via ui-router. I'm thinking I might need to give iron router something to display like an empty tag.

SOLUTION: See my answer below, for a coded example check out the github here https://github.com/cleor41/router-example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

EDIT: IF anyone wants to see an example, check out the link here https://github.com/cleor41/router-example

Instead of trying to sidestep iron router I had to use it, at least for the initial page load. My initial index.html changed from this.

```
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <base href="/">
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <navbar></navbar>
  <div ui-view></div>
</body>
```

to this

```
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <base href="/">
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
```

And I created a template that encapsulated the body.

```
<template name="default">
  <navbar></navbar>
  <div ui-view></div>
</template>
```

Last but not least I had to change my iron route to this.

```
Router.route('/(.*)', function(){
  this.render('default');
});
```

This works since iron router will only render a template once and then the ui router kicks in. My views don't display twice, I can use Houston Admin and the two routers play nice.

NOTE: It should be noted that if you want to use Houston Admin alongside ui router, the ui router will need to catch all of the admin/* routes and then event.preventDefault() inside of $stateChangeStart. This way "urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/")" doesn't mess with the address bar when you're on the Meteor side of things.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue with orionjs and angular ui.ruoter, where did you add in the "stateChangeStart" can you show me an example?

Comment: Yep for sure. You can either create a new meteor project and run 'yo lunar-eclipse' or actually I'll do it for you and link you to the repo, give me a sec.

Comment: @vimes1984 Here ya go, check out the example here https://github.com/cleor41/router-example

Comment: Let me know if you need anything else or a better explanation

Comment: OK I've pushed up what I have to the repo: https://github.com/vimes1984/yeti
my routers are defined in: https://github.com/vimes1984/yeti/blob/master/client/js/configs/appconfig/routers/mainrouters.js
and my template is under index.html it seems to render the actual template just not the ui-view...

Comment: Okay let me give it a look, I'll get back to you in a sec

Comment: Since you're using a different router, can you create a different question and I'll try and help you there? Other people might have the same question.

Comment: @vimes1984 At a glance I think the issue might be the ng-app on the body tag. It looks like you have it going from angular -> meteor -> angular (since the template is placed inside of the body tag by meteor) when it should go meteor -> angular. Try placing ng-app on an element in the template. Idt you even need the ng-app directive though, your angular app should be bootstrapped manually and then handled by ui-router. Or at least thats how I did it. Check out app.ng.js in the client/lib directory

Comment: I like how you set your project up too, I'm going to take a few notes

Comment: One last thing, if you have blaze inside of ng-app, I think you have to use the meteor-include directive.

Comment: Did that help you out?

Comment: it did thank you :D I ended up ripping out the orionJS and building my own though :D

Comment: Thank you for this high quality answer. This is for angular 1. Anyone tried with angular 2?

Answer (score 4):

If there are routes you want to be handled in one router but not the other (doesn't matter which one), you should add that route to both routes to handle, but in one of them don't do anything when it is handled.

You have to do this so that the default behaviour of that route won't happen (usually a redirect to somewhere).

If this answer doesn't help, please copy/paste your routes here so I can better look at what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

Acutally. You don't need to define template name="index" /template. You just need to define 
Router.route('/', function(){

}); (At the top level of route.ng.js)

No need to render anything inside Router.route, and also, the index.html should be as it was. And define correspondent state in ui-router:
.state('admin1',{
            url: '/admin'
        })
        .state('admin2',{
            url: '/admin/*path'
        });

And then everything will just work fine. This is how I did it.